# List users in Linux

Tags: linux, unix

How can I list in alphabetical order all users and also for the first 10 users to see user ID info (column 5).
I know for the first part of the question that I can use like `cat /etc/passwd | cut -d ':' -f1`, but how about the second part? should i use "for" or "if" or something like this?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the header with `grep` and use `cut`:

```
cat /etc/passwd | grep -v '^#' | cut -d: -f1,5
```

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU awk:

```
  awk -F: '{ 
              users[cnt++]=$1 # Set up an array with the users (first : separated field) as the value 
           } 
       END { 
              PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_str_asc"; Set the array sort order to value ascending
              for ( i in users ) { # Loop through each entry in the array
                                   if ( cnt1 <= 4) { # Only print the first 5
                                                      print users[i];
                                                      cnt1++ # Use to track number of prints
                                   } 
              } 
            }' /etc/passwd
```

One liner

```
 awk -F: '{ users[cnt++]=$1 } END { PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_str_asc";for ( i in users ) { if ( cnt1 <= 4) { print users[i];cnt1++ } } }' /etc/passwd
```